# How to use Firebase v2 and Firebase v3 on the same page?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'd like to migrate my firebase.com data to the new firebase.google.com, moving some stuff from firebase.com nodes to firebase.google.com storage.

Thus, I need to embed into the same page Firebase v2 SDK and Firebase v3 SDK.

My concern is both SDK are using the same `Firebase` global variable, making it impossible to use both APIs at the same time.

Do you know of any possibility to rename either Firebase v2 SDK of Firebase v3 SDK global variable (something like a noConflict()) ?
Or maybe allow me to first load one of the SDK, then rename manually the global variable and load the second SDK ?

Note : I'm in the browser, not in a NodeJS app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around my issue by using Firebase 3.x SDK on my page, and access my "old" Firebase instance through manual REST API implementation (not a big deal to achieve, the REST API is ratherly simple to use)

Answer (score 2):

There is no supported way to use the Firebase 2.x and 3.x SDKs in the same page.

You can continue to use the Firebase 2.x SDK in your page after you upgrade your existing project into the new firebase.google.com console. But if you want to use new functionality, the entire page will have to use the new 3.x SDK.

Comment: My concern is on my "old" firebase instance, I'm using ~98% of my data (~60GB) as something I could store into new firebase instance "storage". I cannot use the standard old firebase -> new firebase migration tool since 60GB of "database space" is far than the same expense as 60GB of "storage space". That's why I decided to code my own migration tool (which should not be very complicated in my case) and need to be able to both authenticate on old & new instance at the same time, and use 3.x SDK features as well (particularly storage() API)